# How can I diagnose why my launchd task isn't running on schedule?

Tags: macos, scheduled-tasks, launchd

I've read the `launchd.plist` man page, [Is launchd supposed to pick up "missed" events?](https://superuser.com/questions/542639/is-launchd-supposed-to-pick-up-missed-events), and [launchd seems ignore StartCalendarInterval on Yosemite](https://superuser.com/questions/822329/launchd-seems-ignore-startcalendarinterval-on-yosemite) but none of those have allowed me to diagnose why my launchd task is not running.

I have a task scheduled to run every day at 10:35, often my laptop is asleep then and so the task should be started when the laptop wakes in those cases (and run normally when the laptop was awake).

What I actually see is that the task rarely runs on its own and I consistently have to run it with `launchctl start com.arewesmallyet.update`, though it runs fine (once) when I do so.

`launchctl list | fgrep -i arewe` gives:

```
-   0   com.arewesmallyet.update
```

The output of `launchctl print gui/501/com.arewesmallyet.update` is:

```
com.arewesmallyet.update = {
    active count = 0
    path = /Users/camdennarzt/Developer/Bash/dot-files/Library/LaunchAgents/com.arewesmallyet.update.plist
    state = waiting

    program = /Users/camdennarzt/Developer/Ruby/script.sh
    arguments = {
        /Users/camdennarzt/Developer/Ruby/script.sh
    }

    working directory = /Users/camdennarzt/Developer/Ruby/arewesmallyet

    stdout path = /Users/camdennarzt/Developer/Ruby/arewesmallyet/log/update.log
    stderr path = /Users/camdennarzt/Developer/Ruby/arewesmallyet/log/update_err.log
    global environment = {
        PATH => /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
    }

    inherited environment = {
        DISPLAY => /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.8iIoQIK3yn/org.macosforge.xquartz:0
        SSH_AUTH_SOCK => /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.YUM1kEhk5R/Listeners
        Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render => /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.flahy7F91R/Render
    }

    environment = {
        XPC_SERVICE_NAME => com.arewesmallyet.update
    }

    domain = com.apple.xpc.launchd.user.501.100006.Aqua
    asid = 100006
    minimum runtime = 10
    exit timeout = 5
    runs = 3
    successive crashes = 0
    excessive crashing = 0
    last exit code = 0

    event triggers = {
        com.arewesmallyet.update.268435473 => {
            state = 0
            service = com.arewesmallyet.update
            stream = com.apple.launchd.calendarinterval.501
            monitor = com.apple.UserEventAgent-Aqua
            descriptor = {
                "Minute" => 35
                "Hour" => 10
            }
        }
    }

    endpoints = {
    }

    dynamic endpoints = {
    }

    pid-local endpoints = {
    }

    instance-specific endpoints = {
    }

    event channels = {
        "com.apple.launchd.calendarinterval" = {
            port = 0x4991b
            active = 0
            managed = 1
            reset = 0
            hide = 0
        }
    }

    sockets = {
    }

    spawn type = daemon

    properties = {
        partial import = 0
        launchd bundle = 0
        xpc bundle = 0
        keepalive = 0
        runatload = 0
        dirty at shutdown = 0
        low priority i/o = 0
        low priority background i/o = 0
        legacy timer behavior = 0
        exception handler = 0
        multiple instances = 0
        supports transactions = 0
        supports pressured exit = 0
        enter kdp before kill = 0
        wait for debugger = 0
        app = 0
        system app = 0
        creates session = 0
        inetd-compatible = 0
        inetd listener = 0
        abandon process group = 0
        one-shot = 0
        requires reap = 0
        event monitor = 0
        penalty box = 0
        pended non-demand spawn = 0
        role account = 0
        launch only once = 0
        system support = 0
        app-like = 0
        inferred program = 1
        joins gui session = 0
        joins host session = 0
        parameterized sandbox = 0
        resolve program = 0
        abandon coalition = 0
        extension = 0
        nano allocator = 0
        no initgroups = 0
        start on fs mount = 0
    }
}
```